# How can I replace Wordpress to Drupal?

Tags: wordpress, drupal-7

I have a live website which I make in Wordpress, and I want it change to Drupal. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal is different CMS from the WordPress. You will need to create website in Drupal, create similar theme in Drupal, and then you will need to export content from the WordPress site and import into Drupal...

If your current WordPress site has lot of custom work or using plugins for different features, you will need to make sure you code the same functionality or get similar plugins on Drupal to have similar functionality in new site.

Here is official guide from Drupal:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/migrating-to-drupal/migrating-from-wordpress